# Including custom jQuery in header.php for specific category page

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a few category pages that require a specific advertising banner, and I am trying to use conditional (is_category``) with custom jQuery code to accomplish this.

The code:

```
<?php if(is_category('Faces')): ?>
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery('#banner-area img').attr('src', '123.jpg');

</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The page:

http://www.loft-asia.com/category/faces/

And it doesn't work... I've already tried an alert box and it works, so the conditional script on the page is working.

What am I doing wrong? Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should wait the proper moment to execute your script: [$(document).ready()](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aIntroducing_%24%28document%29.ready%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you have this block repeating four times:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

/jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#banner-area img').attr('src', '123.jpg');
});

</script>
```

You need to add it once and remove the `\` present

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#banner-area img').attr('src', '123.jpg');
});
</script>
```